Realized vol, implied vol, and gamma scalping
First of all, apologies for my lack of knowledge in derivatives trading. So I've been spending a lot of time, in the past few days, trying to understand gamma scalping... and got really confused.
Here is what I think I understand:

I went thru the derivation of the following calculations
$$ P\&L_{[0,T]} = \int_0^T \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(t,S_t,\sigma^2_{t,\text{impl.}})S_t^2( \sigma^2_{t,\text{real.}} - \sigma^2_{t,\text{impl.}})\,dt$$

Here is what I think I don't understand:

From equation above, gamma scalping will only make sense if $\sigma^2_{t,\text{real.}} > \sigma^2_{t,\text{impl.}}$ which is a little counter intuitive to me because I thought implied vol is always higher than realized vol? Or, it should really be the expected realized vol in the future?
I also read about this post (which is super helpful): Delta Hedging with fixed Implied Volatility to get rid of vega?. In this post, the answer explained the difference between whether m2m implied vol. So if I only want to look at pure gamma pnl, I assume I should ignore m2m implied vol, hence a 0 pnl from vega, correct? And I'll be always looking at the implied vol I paid (at purchase) and compare that to the actual realized vol for gamma pnl?

Thanks!

a) Your PnL formula is correct and tells you that you want realized vol to be larger than implied vol to have positive PnL. What makes you think that implied vol is "always" higher then realized vol? b) I do not think a sane options trader will ever run that trading strategy (whose macabre name won't come over my lips) without ever updating his or her implied vol.

@Kurt G. So if someone write an option, he/she would sell at a premium right? check this answer https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77318/implied-volatility-greater-than-realized-volatility-at-all-strikes. That intuitively makes sense to me, but so does the PnL formula... so I am not sure what's missing. Maybe in the PnL formula, the implied vol is the vol at purchase and realized vol should be the expectation of future realized vol? Thanks!

In the end I decided to write a brief answer:

Let's accept that typically implied vol (IV) is larger then realized vol (RV). This is another good answer making this plausible.

Your PnL formula is correct. Here is a proof. The PnL should therefore typically be negative.

This begs the question why there is the consensus that this trading strategy (hedging a position that has positive gamma) "makes money".

The answer is that there is another principle at work: in practice we cannot hedge continuously but instead only at discrete times. When we are long gamma we have bought the option. Therefore, when the stock price rises we must sell $N(d_1)$ shares. If we do this discretely there is a time lag and we sell at a higher price than the guy that aims to hedge continuously. Therefore we are better off than that other guy. Similar arguments apply when the stock price falls. This explains intuitively what traders like when they hedge: positive gamma. They abhor nothing more than negative gamma.


